# Java | Selenium | Using Stream to return single Webelement from a list of weblements

Tags: java, selenium, java-stream

I'm trying to filter a list of webelements down to a single webelement by the elements's innerText. In c#, I would use a linq where clause. In Java, I'm trying to use stream but I can't figure out why I'm getting the incompatible type error (required: org.openQA.selenium.Webelement. Found: java.util.optional)

```
public List <WebElement> emp = driver.findElements(By.className("employee"));

public String correctName = driver.findElement(By.id("name")).getText();

public WebElement getName(){
    WebElement correct = emp.stream().filter((element) -> element.getText().contains(correctName)).findFirst();
   return correct;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is fair. `findFirst` returns an `Optional`. You have to get the object explicitly like so.

```
WebElement correct = emp.stream().filter((element) -> element.getText().contains(correctName)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

So if the `Optional` is not empty, it will return the value, otherwise it will return `null`. Note `get` on an `Optional` is not recommended to use and it'll be deprecated in future.